# change currency and remove .00 paid membership pro

Tags: wordpress

I want to change paid membership pro price currency and remove decimal on the the price (.00). But i didn't find any instruction to do this.

Would you please help me. Thanks

Comment: Try contacting the makers of the plugin or theme, instead of asking it in here without any code to show...

Comment: I found the solution. The change the currency and remove decimal, you need to edit currencies.php in the include folder of plugin. you can find the example of removing decimal in the file too. Korean currency has a line which removes the decimal for it and i just copy and paste it. I hope it helps others who had the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
        'IRR' => array( 
              'name' => __('Iranian Rial (&#65020;)', 'paid-memberships-pro' ),
             'symbol' => '&#65020;',
             'position' => 'right',
            'decimals' => 0,

        ),

        'IRT' => array( 
              'name' => __('Iranian Toman (تومان)', 'paid-memberships-pro' ),
              'symbol' => ' تومان' ,
             'position' => 'right',
            'decimals' => 0,

        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for changing the currency and remove decimal, you need to edit currencies.php in the include folder of plugin. you can find the example of removing decimal in the file too. Korean currency has a line which removes the decimal for it and i just copy and paste it. I hope it helps others who had the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can change currency and remove decimal in General options -> Payment Settings

Comment: Are you talking about Woocommerce?